# Java library for multidimensionial continuous optimization

Tags: java, regression, mathematical-optimization

I need Java library that performs gradient descent (preferred) or other multidimensional continuous optimization methods. Specifically, I need it to find logit regression coefficients. Does anyone knows such a lib?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/) - it's a package for Data Mining and Machine Learning. For example, logistic regression is in [this class](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/SimpleLogistic.html).