# Can anybody please recommend me a good library to apply machine learning in java/scala?

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning

I am trying to implement machines learning in java or scala environment. Can anybody please recommend me a good library to study and use?

So far, the algorithm that I am going to use will be logistic regression and SVN.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) suits your needs.

Comment: Check out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296197/java-library-for-multidimensionial-continuous-optimization, with a direct link to the class addressing logistic regression.

Answer (score 2):

Have a  look at [scala0-recog](http://code.google.com/p/scala-recog/)  or if you want a big toolbox then try [scalaNLP](http://www.scalanlp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a lib build on top of hadoop called Mahout that might help you. It has use cases in distributed computing and parallelization. Hth